# jack_client_open won't connect to jackdbus

Tags: c, dbus, jack

I have a gentoo amd64 Linux system with jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.9.5 installed.

I'm trying to get the list of available jack input devices using the following code:

```
#include <jack/jack.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

const char **jack_get_input_devices() {

const char **ports;
const char *client_name = "tuxinstudio";
const char *server_name = NULL;
jack_options_t options = JackNoStartServer;
jack_status_t status;
jack_client_t *client;

client = jack_client_open(client_name,options,&status,server_name);
if (client == NULL) {
    g_debug("jack client open failed. status 0x%2.0x",status);                
}
if (status & JackServerStarted) {
    g_debug("JACK server started\n");
}
if (status & JackNameNotUnique) {
    client_name = jack_get_client_name(client);
    g_debug("unique name `%s' assigned\n", client_name);
}    
ports = jack_get_ports (client, NULL, NULL,JackPortIsPhysical|JackPortIsInput);
if (ports == NULL) {
    g_debug("no physical capture ports\n");
}    
g_print("sizeof ports: %lu",sizeof ports);
return ports;
}
```

it seems that jack cannot connect to dbus server.

this is the output of the execution:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
jack_get_ports called with a NULL client
```

how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was with jackdbus server, i didn't start it properly.

i have a firewire audio card.
so now I use the following:

```
alsa_control start ds firewire
```

then it's able to properly connect to jack.